Network block device sharing over sctp/dccp
As we work with a local drive, we create read and write requests to the backend block devices. In general, they can not be and should not be fulfilled in their issue order. For example, write requests can happen with a delay (typically, in free time as the write cache is too big), and also read requests can be served much more quickly from the page cache.
Thing are becoming much more problematic if we work with a network shared block device. The 3 ways I know:

nbd, alias network block device
iscsi, that is scsi protocol over a tcp socket
and we can also use ordinary files mounted on an nfs or cifs directory.

However, things are not so simple over a network connection. That happens typically over tcp, and tcp serializes the communication, do we want or not. Thus, concurrent requests over a tcp-shared network block device, must be fulfilled as they arrived over the network.
That is not always the correct way to do, not even in the case of today with broadly used SSD backends, simply because cached memory pages could be served on the spot.
In my opinion, the obvious solution would be to use some more advanced protocol to handle correctness and giving more freedom over the ordering of the requests. That could be maybe sctp or dccp. They are well developed protocols in the linux kernel, and they make possible to reorder the answers, compared to their issue timestamp or network arrival order.
Does such a thing exist? As far I can see,

nbd is tcp-only
nfs can be also udp, but that is sub-optimal
iscsi is also tcp-only.

Does some way exist to use some more advanced protocol for the network sharing of a block device?

SATA, nvme and all modern SCSI derivates do support command queuing. And that over their respective links – none of which have "parallel" command lines for multiple requests.
You are imagining a problem that isn't there – iSCSI (via TCP) fully supports Tagged Command Queuing (TCQ), which is exactly what you describe: asynchronous completion of commands being possible over any serial link. Hence, and luckily, concurrent requests over a tcp-shared network block device, must be fulfilled as they arrived over the network is an incorrect conclusion!
So, the answer to your question becomes:

iSCSI with target devices that support TCQ fully support out-of-order replies
NFS is also fully capable of concurrently serving multiple requests – the underlying RPC interface supports that. How that is implemented in Linux (it certainly is, sunrpc doesn't really make it easy to enforce strict ordering) however is a detail I don't know. However, the fact alone that you can list two directories large at the same time from a single NFS client machine proves that you don't have to worry about replies having to be in order of requests!
nbd I don't know intimately enough; however, the protocol specification explicitly mentions that a server might server requests out of order, and the independent request and reply logical packet types suggest that this isn't a big deal, and if I'd have to take a guess, a multithreaded server implementation like nbdkit will inherently have that ability to answer to whatever got done first first.


Right. But what if there is a noisy signal? In advanced protocols, the timeout/retransmit of a damaged request would not delay the others.

OK; that's a very special concern. The things you mentioned above are usually done over low-latency low-loss networks. For high-latency and/or high-loss, you really don't want to access block devices, but work at a higher level of abstraction (e.g object storage).
